# how to create a different Public Activity based on a model attribute? (rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a posts model that I am tracking using the PublicActivity gem as seen below

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PublicActivity::Model
  tracked except: :destroy, owner: ->(controller, model) { controller && controller.current_user }
```

Here's the link to more info about the gem: https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity

In the Post table, one of the attributes that I have is "discussion".

```
create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                         :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                         :null => false
    t.boolean  "discussion",          :default => false
  end
```

If discussion == true, I want to display a different kind of text message in the PublicActivity stream.

Right now, I'm using this in view for ALL posts

```
<li>

  <% if activity.trackable_type == "Post" %>
    <%= link_to activity.owner.name, activity.owner if activity.owner %> posted new content <span class="timestamp"> <%= time_ago_in_words(activity.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  <% else %>
   <%= link_to activity.owner.name, activity.owner if activity.owner %> made a comment on a post<span class="timestamp"> <%= time_ago_in_words(activity.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Here's the controller for the view above

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc")
  end
  end
```

I want to include a new type of view message where it says "user created a new discussion" which is based on the boolean value of the attribute inside the post table. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

`activity.trackable` will give the model that is being tracked. it is a polymorphic association.

Lets say the user has created a new post and discussion is set to true. 
In that case `activity.trackable` will give you the Post model object and all its methods will work as normal, so you `activity.trackable.discussion` will give you `true/false`, based on the example i said, it will return `true`

in your view you can do something like this

```
<% if activity.trackable.discussion %>
  User created a discussion
<% else %>
  User created a post
<% end %>
```

Hope that helps.